# Spherical K-means Clustering in R

Tags: r, clustering, k-means

I have a large data set that I would like to cluster using spherical K means algorithm. However, I am relatively new to this subject and R in general. Most of my knowledge is self taught and I am still in the beginning stages- I have read all about K means clustering in the past few days and I would like to apply it to my own project (184 rows of 4000+ columns containing measurements in decimal values). How and where do I start?

I am trying to teach myself how to go about this in R but I can't seem to find examples online on how to do this, or at least they don't apply to my case. I was wondering if anyone here would know about a step by step tutorial or has access to a script in which a spherical k means clustering has been conducted in R, and if you could share it with me. I have found a few papers but they are very advanced, and most are for text clustering and not numeric values.

I hope this question is not too vague. Does anyone have experience in this subject and could guide me on which steps I have to take to get started? Absolute beginner here, so I apologize if I am completely wrong to ask such a question on this platform.

Thank you for taking time out of your day to read this!

Answer (score 4):

You'll want R package `skmeans`.

[CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/skmeans/index.html) | [Journal of Statistical Software](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v50/i10/paper)

JSS citation:

> Hornik, Feinerer, Kober, & Buchta. (2012). Spherical k-means clustering. *Journal of Statistical Software, 50* (10).

By the way, this came up on the first page of a Google search for "spherical k means R". Gotta love adaptive results... the more research you do, the easier it gets!